# R nzchar error: argument is length zero

Tags: r

This code is generating an error, but why? I thought nzchar was the proper vehicle to check whether a field is empty?

```
 for(i in 1:length(mega$hour_start)){
     temp = mega$hour_start[i][[1]]
     if (!nzchar(temp)){
         next
     }
 }
Error in if (!nzchar(temp)) { : argument is of length zero
```

I am using nzchar to avoid errors, and I don't know how to avoid an error this function is generating.

Here's what the data looks like: mega$hour_start is sometimes a numeric array and sometimes empty:

```
> mega$hour_start[45:50]
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
 [1] 11 11 10 16 12 12 11 11 11 11 22 22 14 14 14  6  6 17 17 17 15 15 15 11 20 20 20 20 12 10  7

[[6]]
NULL
```

What's the proper way to be looping through this dataframe column so as not to generate errors? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the test to be

```
if (is.null(temp)) {
  next
}
```

if the intention is to test `temp` for `NULL`-ness. In other words, if `temp == NULL`, jump to the next iteration of the loop.

`nzchar()` is intended for the determination of non-zero strings in a vector.